# How does the properties inside of the methods work here?

Tags: javascript, class, methods, properties

Heey,

I'm a beginner learning JavaScript and I was seeing a tutorial of how to make a calculator by WebDevSimplified channel on youtube, I'd say I understood most of the code, but I have a doubt about some properties created inside of the methods of the class. For example:

```
class Calculator {
    constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
      this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
      this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
      this.clear()
    }
  
    clear() {
      this.currentOperand = ''
      this.previousOperand = ''
      this.operation = undefined
    }
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong, he creates the class, then the constructor, and finally he set two parameters to it and assigned these parameters to two properties.
What I'm not understanding is the properties inside of the methods(the "clear" method for example), in this code above he sets the parameters: currentOperand, previousOperand and operation. How do the "system" understand that these are the current and previous operand numbers that are going to display in the screen since it's not linked to the HTML. I'll put the link of the entire project bellow.

https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Vanilla-JavaScript-Calculator

Comment: Nothing in those lines makes the interpreter understand that these are the operand numbers that are going to be displayed. That's happening only in the [`updateDisplay` method](https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Vanilla-JavaScript-Calculator/blob/master/script.js#L76-L85)! The linking to the concrete html [happens outside of that class](https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Vanilla-JavaScript-Calculator/blob/master/script.js#L89-L126).

Answer (score -1):

copy and paste this

```
class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.clear()
}

clear() {
  this.currentOperand = ''
  this.previousOperand = ''
  this.operation = undefined
}
```

but if you have tried it and it does not work maybe make sure your html is connected to the js maybe thats the issue

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to describe how this code snippet works and why this is better than the OP's code. I cannot even tell what you changed in that code.

Comment: is your js connected to the html make sure maybe that's the problem the working code is the one I sent you copy and paste it if it works its an error with your code other wise everything is right maybe you did not link your js to the html

Comment: I am not the question author! The OP already has working code - they just want to understand how it works. "*the working code is the one I sent you*" - well yes, since you copy-pasted the working code from the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).